# Photoshop display doesn't show everything I've drawn

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Photoshop CS6 and I have a strange problem.

I opened Photoshop one day and it looks as if a setting has changed.

While I am working on it and I zoom out to see the full page, a few lines that I have drawn disappear, but when I zoom in they are there. Also the transform controls look different; it used to be a solid black line and now it's dotted and until I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> leaves the marks of the previews location of the object (see the picture below) .

[image: Example of the problem]

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, most of what you describe sounds like normal behavior.  Temporarily leaving the old location outline sounds like something isn't being refreshed.  But lines disappearing when you zoom out could just be "rounding" (the lines get too thin to display).  The solid line vs. dotted line sounds like a border vs. an object selection.  If the software had an update, it's not unusual for appearance items to change.  Can you be more specific to clarify exactly what changed and how?

Comment: fixer1234 thanks a lot for your reply. I know that usually photoshop does that to lines on the display but this time I think is quite sensitive. I don't think that it had an update. I fell like photoshop tries to keep the resolution very low on the display, maybe because it runs faster this way? I am not sure, is that possible?

Do you know how to change the doted line back to the solid one? As now the doted line stays on the screen for a few seconds after even if I have press the enter button.

Comment: There isn't much diagnostic information to go on.  It would be useful to provide your basic system specs.  Just some generic advice, Photoshop needs a lot of memory.  Problems like the delayed screen cleanup may be due to that.  If you have limited RAM, work on big projects, have a lot of stuff running in the background, etc., Photoshop can run out of memory and start swapping active content between RAM and the hard drive, which really slows it down.